# How does asp.net webapi interprets empty or no accept header

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

How does ASP.NET web Api interprets an empty/no accept header in the request?
will it by default take it as application/json, etc...?

Answer (score 0):

Considering w3 specifications the web-servers can negotiate to each other based on these rules including allowing request method types (GET, POST, etc), content-type and etc.

If you want to accept an additional header in your webserver you must define that variable in your webserver configurations, despite not defining this variable cause your webserver won't receive requests containing that variable in the request header. Default content-type in http request is text/plain.

Comment: does this mean it all depends on server configurations??

Comment: Take a look at this link and you got it:
https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpprotocol/customheaders